# `<tr id='item-<xsl:value-of select="$item.count" />'>` : How to do it correctly?

Tags: html, variables, xslt-1.0, identifier

XSL is not my daily job, but I'm trying to assign ascending IDs with a common prefix to table rows created (to be able to iterate through them using JavaScript in order to do some spreadsheet-like calculations).

I managed to get the ascending count into a variable named `item.count`, but I'm unable (even after searching quite a lot) to get that into the `id=` attribute of `<tr>`.

Using `<tr id='item-<xsl:value-of select="$item.count" />'>` I got a "not well-formed" message from Firefox.

The template in question looks like this:

```xsl
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="item.count" select="count(preceding::item)" />'
    <tr id='item-<xsl:value-of select="$item.count" />'>
      <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$item.count" />: <xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:comment>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
      <!-- ... -->
      <td>(output)</td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

(The comment is just to verify that the counter works as intended for now)

Comment: Read about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates). P.S. Counting preceding items is not a good way to number items; consider using either `position()` or `xsl:number`.

Comment: So "the curlies" in `<tr id="item-{$item.count}">` seems to have fixed the problem (before I had tried without the curly parentheses without success). However I thought that those curlies are a XSLT 3 feature and browsers only support XSLT 1... Well, I didn't say that the whole thing runs in the (Firefox) browser.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I had found `xsl:number`, but all the examples I found were either trivial, or too complex (here at SO) to grasp. I could look into `position`...

Comment: The link above is to the XSLT 1.0 specification. You can ask separately about numbering - but please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.